# How to create a node from an other node template?

Tags: 8, nodes, forms

I would like to have a form for the creation of a node (let's name it news) when you are on the page of an other type of node (let's name it movie). So on /node/31 (of type movie) I would like to have the node content and a form to create a news

I thought about using a Webform but after all it felt like trying to hack the Webform with a trick. Moreover since the form already exists (at path node/add/node_name), I might be able to reuse it but I don't know if it is really possible.

What should be the right way to do it ? With a webform ? By exposing the form for the specific node ? By creating a custom form ? Maybe an other solution I didn't think about ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [Form Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/formblock)

> Enables the presentation of user registration, site wide contact, or
>   **node creation forms** in blocks

Select your content type for the form. Place block in region and for visibility select the other content type.

If you rather render the block using a template file, ex: node--movie.html.twig you can use [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) and print it out using `{{ drupal_block('block_id') }}`

Comment: The module is working (not with Twig Tweak, I've got a message saying that the block is defective but the module is still working).

Answer (score 1):

That's actually a task for [Inline Entity Form](https://www.drupal.org/project/inline_entity_form).

> Provides a widget for inline management (creation, modification,
>   removal) of referenced entities. The primary use case is the parent ->
>   children one (product display -> products, order -> line items, etc.),
>   where the child entities are never managed outside the parent form.
>   Existing entities can also be referenced.

It will simply add some widgets for entity/node reference fields that then let you create and edit the referencing entities/nodes in a node form.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You may try `drupal_entity_form` provided by the [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) module.

```
{{ drupal_entity_form('node', values={type: 'news'}) }}
```